# Como posso retornar zero na frente de outros numeros?

Tags: php

Tenho um registro em meu BD MySQL, exemplo: `A0001` e preciso pegar esse valor e ir somando exemplo `A0001` `+ 1` = `A0002`.

Fiz o seguinte:

```
$texto = "A0001";
$novotexto = substr($texto, -4);
$soma = ($novotexto+1);

echo $soma;
```

O retorno foi `A2`, mas eu gostaria que ficasse `A0002`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Poderia fazer o seguinte, utilizando o [str_pad](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php)

```
$texto = "A0001";
$novotexto = substr($texto, -4);

$tempIni = substr($texto, 0,1); //Guardar inicio na variavel

$soma = ($novotexto+1);

$resultado = $tempIni . str_pad($soma, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $resultado;
```

Answer (score 4):

Caso o tamanho se fixo, use a função `str_pad()` para adicionar número variável de zeros a esquerda sendo no maximo quatro dígitos e no final pode concatenar a letra.

```
$formatado = 'A'. str_pad($soma, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $formatado;
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize [str_pad](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php), para colocar zeros a esquerda e depois concatena o `A` novamente, exemplo:

```
<?php

$texto = "A0001";
$novotexto = substr($texto, -4);
echo $soma = 'A'.str_pad(($novotexto+1), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

[Veja rodando ONLINE](https://ideone.com/zNp3t5)